# JAXB unmarshalling extremely slow with (SAXON-HE) on the classpath

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, saxon, quickfixj

I've discovered that having quickfixj-all as a maven dependency in a project which uses JAXB to unmarshal XML results in extremely slow unmarshalling.

Here is the console output of the Unit Test when quickfixj-all is not on the classpath:

```
2019-12-15 20:02:26.067  INFO 1676 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded Repository XML in 506ms
2019-12-15 20:02:26.067  INFO 1676 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loading Phrases XML
2019-12-15 20:02:26.068  INFO 1676 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loading from /C:/Users/Beirti/git/jaxb-performance/target/test-classes/FIX.5.0SP2_EP249_en_phrases.xml
2019-12-15 20:02:30.081  INFO 1676 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded Phrases XML in 4013ms
2019-12-15 20:02:30.081  INFO 1676 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded JAXB Objects
```

However, when you include quickfixj-all on the classpath, it take far far longer.

```
2019-12-15 20:03:39.403  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded Repository XML in 881ms
2019-12-15 20:03:39.403  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loading Phrases XML
2019-12-15 20:03:39.404  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loading from /C:/Users/Beirti/git/jaxb-performance/target/test-classes/FIX.5.0SP2_EP249_en_phrases.xml
2019-12-15 20:06:49.584  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded Phrases XML in 190180ms
2019-12-15 20:06:49.584  INFO 2912 --- [           main] c.b.fix.repository.FIXRepositoryHelper   : Loaded JAXB Objects
```

This seems to be due to the transitive dependency `quickfixj-all -> quickfixj-codegenerator -> Saxon-HE:9.8.0-4`. You can replicate the issue by including this dependency alone.

I can see inside the Saxon-HE jar is a file in META-INF which overrides the `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` and sets it to `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`. If I delete that file from the jar directly and rerun my test, it completes quickly.

Is there a way to override this TransformerFactory in my own project without hacking the Saxon jar? (I have tried adding the default one to src/main/resources/META-INF/services but it does not work)

This project contains a few classes and configuration which demonstrate the issue: https://github.com/beirtipol/jaxb-performance

Comment: @khmarbaise FYI, found the root cause and it doesn't appear maven related after all:)

Comment: Can't you include just the QFJ artifacts that you really need as dependency? E.g. `core` and `messages`? I think you can also exclude transitive dependencies.

Comment: I could do that, but what if I needed Saxon (for some reason) on my classpath?

Comment: Check if there are any bugs open which could explain this? Maybe https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4341 ?? Disclaimer: I don't know Saxon (or its internals), so forgive me if this bug has nothing to do with the actual problem.

Comment: I would Saxon expect to set that property to `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl`. Isn't `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl` the default of the Oracle JRE? As for setting properties without changing the jar, isn't there a command line option for Java to set properties e.g. `-Djava.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen I tried adding that property when running the unit test but it doesn't seem to speed things up so I'm guessing the transformerfactory from Saxon is still being used

Comment: Did you try with an older version to check if you are affected by the bug I mentioned earlier?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, the transitive version of Saxon being pulled in is earlier than the one referenced in the bug report, but it's possibly something for the quickfixj team to look at. I'm still trying to find a non-hacky way to fix the issue, which may mean switching out Saxon versions. I haven't found the right one yet and don't know what impact it might have on the quickfixj libraries which use it

Comment: Hmm, in the bug report someone switched from an older version to a new major version. So it could be that the bug has been introduced somewhere in between and not in that particular version the user switched to. QFJ uses Saxon not on runtime but only for generating code from the data dictionaries. Disclaimer: I am from QFJ team.

Answer (score 1):

Coming to this late, but there seem to be two approaches to solving this problem:

(a) try to prevent Saxon being loaded

(b) work out why you're getting a performance problem when Saxon is loaded

The best way of doing (a) (if you need to have Saxon on the classpath) is to set the system property `javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory` to the name of the `TransformerFactory` implementation that you want to load.

The best way of doing (b) is NOT to search the issues list looking for Saxon performance problems; it's rather unlikely that your particular problem will match a reported bug. You need to tackle this top-down the way you tackle any other performance issue, by setting up measurements and drilling down to establish where the costs are being incurred. As a general rule Saxon is faster than Xalan, but it's certainly not the case that it will always be faster, and you might just have hit one of those cases.

The performance discrepancy here (from 4s to 190s) is so severe that there's obviously something going badly wrong. Paradoxically, big performance problems are usually much easier to solve than small performance problems because there's usually a simple cause -- once you can find it.

Comment: That flag didn't seem to be picked up either by my application at startup or by my unit tests. I think something to do with the fact that it's specified by the manifest serviceloader in quickfixj

Comment: Does setting jaxp.debug="1" give you any useful diagnostics?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a few suggestions from the comments on the original question:

- Nothing obvious in the bug reports on Saxon. I'm not sure if this is a bug per-se or just poor performance of the Saxon implementaiton of the TransformerFactory.
- Overriding the TransformerFactory at runtime with a System Property is problematic as Java 11 no longer includes some XML processing jars by default, and it's difficult to keep it compatible across runtimes
- Hacking the Saxon jar to remove the TransformerFactory override from the 'services' folder is awful unless you are performing some kind of shading or jar-of-dependencies build where you don't want to keep pristine dependencies.

As one of the QFJ team suggested, Saxon is only required at code-generation time and is not a runtime dependency, so the best solution for this specific issue is to exclude Saxon complete from the quickfixj-all dependency. This addresses my specific issue with QuickFixJ but I'm not entirely thrilled that there isn't a way to override the ServiceLoader.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.quickfixj</groupId>
        <artifactId>quickfixj-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>Saxon-HE</artifactId>
                <groupId>net.sf.saxon</groupId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I won't mark this as the correct answer for a while, I'm hoping that someone can tell me how to remove the TransformerFactory specification from the Saxon jar at runtime